# Macros to insert header row when new group begins

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a new code that will copy and insert the header column (from row 1 of the data) into a list each time the group of data changes. The size of each grouping is different and the sizes change from one month to the next. To add further complication the names of the groupings can change. For example I need the code to break the list down something like this:

```
Header
Corporate
Corporate
Corporate
Insert header
Financial
Financial
Insert header
Public 
etc
```

The data needs to stay on the same sheet so there is no need to move the data anywhere

So far I have thought of something along the lines of this, but don't know the correct syntax to use in order to make this operational:

```
Do forever
‘stop at the end
   If group_cellvalue(vArraycounter) = “” then leave
   Endif
vArraycounter = vArraycounter + 1
   ‘test the current group against that in the previous row if different, insert 
   'header
   If group_cellvalue((vArraycounter) <> group_cellvalue((vArraycounter - 1 ) 
    then
        InsertRow
        InsertHeadingText
        'Increment counter to get back on track
        vArraycounter = vArraycounter + ?
    Endif
End For
```

Any tips or suggestions much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: there will always be an initial column header; there are no gaps in the values going down underneath the initial column header.

Then the code below is a startpoint. Paste it in a module and adapt the `Test` sub so it points to the location of the initial column header.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Headerize Sheet1.Range("A1")
End Sub

Public Sub Headerize(ByVal prngFirstHeader As Excel.Range)
    Dim rngScan As Excel.Range

    Set rngScan = prngFirstHeader.Cells(3, 1)

    Do Until IsEmpty(rngScan.Value)
        If rngScan.Value <> rngScan.Cells(0, 1).Value Then
            prngFirstHeader.Copy
            rngScan.Insert Shift:=XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown
        End If

        Set rngScan = rngScan.Cells(2, 1)
    Loop

    Set rngScan = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: HI. Thanks for this. I am struggling to get this to work- it is using code new to me. I have tried to apply this to my own problem. 
Do I need to declare both subs or is the first an example of one way and the second another? I have tried it with both and just one, with the former the macros seems to do nothing, the latter it disappears off the list of macros when you go to view macros
When setting the values (x, y) am I right in thinking that the left number is row and the right is column?
I'd send the code I had done but don't know how to format on this site, will learn

Comment: My code:
Sub Test(ByVal Header As Excel.Range)
    
    Dim rngScan As Excel.Range

    With Sheets("Annex B Active Staff")
        .Select

        Set rngScan = prngFirstHeader.Cells(3, 12) 'Looking at row 3, column 12

        Do While Not IsEmpty(rngScan.Value)
            If rngScan.Value <> rngScan.Cells(0, 12).Value Then
                prngFirstHeader.Copy
                rngScan.Insert Shift:=XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown
            End If

            Set rngScan = rngScan.Cells(2, 12)
        Loop

        Set rngScan = Nothing

    End With


End Sub

Comment: You can remove the `Test` sub, which was just to show an example call of the `Headerize` sub. All you should have to do is call `Headerize` as-is, from your code, passing it a reference to the first header that has to be repeated down as differences are detected. For example, if your header to be repeated is on worksheet "XYZ" at address C3, put `Headerize ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XYZ").Range("C3")` in your code.